# If no nextjs page use IIS page

Tags: iis, routes, next.js

If deploying nextjs on IIS is there a way to default back to IIS for routing if there is no nextjs page?

I want to use nextjs for my homepage and wiki etc, but there are other pages routed from IIS directly if there is no page jsx?

Eg)

- homepage.com -> loads nextjs page/index.js
- homepage.com/wiki/some-page -> loads nextjs page/wiki/[some-page].js
- homepage.com/viewer -> loads iis/viewer/index.html

Comment: Is your problem solved? I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly, If there is no nextjs page do you wan to use url rewrite directly in iis? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options

1. Front the application with a proxy like nginx and maintain static routing, e.g: `/viewer` -> `/iis/viewer/index.html`
2. Configure your 404 page in nextjs to a redirect. First setup a [custom App with next](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app), then in your App `getInitialProps` which receives a `ctx`

```
// Modified from  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16749#discussioncomment-1604423
      if (ctx.res.statusCode === 404) {
        res.writeHead(301, { Location: '/iis/'+ctx.asPath })
        res.end()
      }
```

Note that appropriate handling when 404 pages are received by IIS would have to be setup on the IIS end.